# Push new object if it's undefined and ignore when it is available

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, push

I want to push new object to a JSON array if it is not available yet and ignore it if available. For example, how do I get ignored log in this code the second time button clicked:

```js
var things = [];

$("#button").click(function(){
things[0]["id456"] != undefined ? console.log("ignored") : things.push({"id456":"clicked"});
$("#output").text(JSON.stringify(things));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='output'></div>
<button id="button">
Click
</button>
```

I know I could do something like this:

```
var strThings = JSON.stringify(things);
var available = strThings.search("id456");
available === -1 ? things.push({"id456":"clicked"}) : console.log("ignored");
```

But I don't think that's the great idea.

Comment: perhaps `things.find(thing => thing.hasOwnProperty("id456")) || things.push({"id456":"clicked"});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
var things = [];

$("#button").click(function() {
  things.some(thing => thing.id456 !== undefined) ? console.log("ignored") : things.push({
    "id456": "clicked"
  });
  $("#output").text(JSON.stringify(things));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='output'></div>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

But if you want my advice, don't try and do that on one line. There's these amazing things called [`if` and `else` statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else):

```js
var things = [];

$("#button").click(function() {
  let containsId456 = things.some(
    thing => thing.id456 !== undefined
  );

  if (containsId456) {
    console.log("ignored");
  } else {
    things.push({"id456": "clicked"});
  }
  $("#output").text(JSON.stringify(things));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='output'></div>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

But lastly, unless I'm missing something, this would be easier with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or an object used as a dictionary of IDs:

```js
var things = new Map();

$("#button").click(function() {
  if (things.has("id456")) {
    console.log("ignored");
  } else {
    things.set("id456", "clicked");
  }
  $("#output").text(JSON.stringify([...things]));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='output'></div>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, this really help to me. But by the way, what is the point using if and else when we can do it in one line?

Comment: @DedenBangkit clarity. That one-liner in the first solution makes no sense at a glance, and is terrible for maintenance of code. You come back to that in a year and I promise you, you'll forget what it was for and it will take you at least 15 minutes to try and figure out what the point of it was.

Comment: But how if I want to return a value of a function? I could do something like this in one line: function() {a logic; return available === -1 ? "true" : "false"};

Comment: @DedenBangkit I have no idea what you're asking... my point is, yes you can almost always manage to do something in one line if you really want to, but almost never _should_ unless it's something fairly straightforward.